# How to add element to array in MatLab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to make a graph of the brightness of a pixel vs the distance from center of that pixel. To do so I used for loops to check each pixel for these values. But when adding them to my array I find that I can't. One of the issues is I have to define the array size first so no values get placed in the right spot. I believe everything else to be working except adding values to the arrays.

I've tried various methods of concatenation to add the values of each pixel to the array. I didn't have any more solutions to try.

```
folder3 = 'C:\Users\slenka\Desktop\Image_Analysis\Subtracted';
    cd('C:\Users\slenka\Desktop\Image_Analysis\Subtracted');
    subtractedFiles = [dir(fullfile(folder3,'*.TIF')); dir(fullfile(folder3,'*.PNG')); dir(fullfile(folder3,'*.BMP')); dir(fullfile(folder3,'*.jpg'))];
    numberOfSubImages= length(subtractedFiles);

    for b = 1 : numberOfSubImages
        subFileName=fullfile(folder3, subtractedFiles(b).name);
        chartImage=imread(subFileName);
        [chartY, chartX, chartNumberOfColorChannels] = size(chartImage);
        ccY= chartY/2;
        ccX= chartX/2;
        c=[ccX,ccY];
        distanceArray=zeros(1,chartX);
        intensityArray=zeros(1,chartY);
        f=1;
        g=1;
        for y=1:chartY
            for x=1:chartX

                D = sqrt((y - c(1)) .^ 2 + (x - c(2)) .^ 2);
                grayScale= impixel(chartImage, x, y);
                distanceArray(f)=[D];
                intensityArray(g)=[grayScale]; 
                f=f+1;
                g=g+1;
            end
        end
        xAxis=distanceArray;
        yAxis=intensityArray;
        plot(xAxis,yAxis);

    end
```

I'm expecting 2 arrays one full of the data values for the light intensity of each pixel in the image, and another for that pixels distance from the center of the image. I am wanting to plot these two arrays as the y and x axis respectively. At the moment the actual results is an entirely empty array full of zeros.

Comment: Are you sure the loop is entered? Have you run the program in the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: Yep, it can get all the way through the loop but the array remains empty, it’s filled with zeros

Comment: Have you checked the values of `D` and `greyscale` halfway through the loops to see if they are ever non-zero? As an aside `f == g == (y-1)*chartX + x`.

Comment: Also do you want `intensityArray(g)=[grayScale]` or `intensityArray(g) = grayScale`?

Comment: Well I'm not sure. When I run through the loop it says that that line of code doesn't work because they're not the same size. I think I fixed it and the matrices are never none zero